# How to save an image in byte Array and get back bytearray into image in grails?

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

i wanted to save an image in byte array..
and save into mongoDb Database.. and get back byte Array into image file
and display on to .GSP page

Domain

```
class Profile{
    static mapWith = "mongo"

    String firstname
    String lastname
    byte[] imgpath
}
```

Controller

```
def saveimage{
    File filepath = new File("C:\\man-of-steel-theme.jpg");


   def encodedData = filepath.bytes;
   profile.imgpath=encodedData;
   profile.save();
}
```

In this am not sure is correct byte array save into mongodb and not able to get image file

Comment: "*not sure is correct byte array*" -> did you verify? "*not able to get image file*" -> did you check the retrieval code?

Comment: is there any other option for byte array.. because i saw most of the people are saving an image in byte array... even i am not sure.. will you guide me... to save an image in mongoDb except string path..

Comment: I am trying, but you are not cooperating.

Comment: Sorry.. Please guide me how to save an image? if you have other way  to do this... please tell me.. i'll try to do your way

Comment: I can't help you when you keep ignoring my first comment.

Comment: 1. i verified into mongoDb.. data is saved into  byte format...[844059]: FF-D8-FF-E1-00 ... 13-F5-FF-00-FF-D9 in this format saves image file in monoDB

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39045/discussion-between-user2446714-and-philipp)

Comment: Have you looked at GridFS for saving larger files (e.g. images) into MongoDB? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/

Answer (score 1):

maybe this can be helpfull for you

```
    import java.awt.Graphics2D
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage

    import javax.imageio.ImageIO
    import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream
    import javax.imageio.stream.MemoryCacheImageInputStream

    class xyzClass {
        def zabcdef(){
            org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile multipartfile = request.getFile('picture')
            if (!multipartfile || multipartfile.getContentType() != 'image/jpeg') {
                render("${message(code:'error.wrong.file.type')}: jpeg")
                return;
            }

            ImageInputStream iis = new MemoryCacheImageInputStream(multipartfile.getInputStream())
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(iis)

            storeImage(image,"foto")
        }

    }



    private storeImage(BufferedImage image, String name) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", os)
        byte[] buf = os.toByteArray()
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf)
        //store
    }
```